# Why would you want to trigger the unique option in add_index in migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

What is the difference between

```
add_index :users, :email
```

and

```
add_index :users, :email, unique: true
```

Why would you want your index to be unique and why does it matter?
I thought add_index is simply just a way for database query to be faster. More of something for the database rather than for us to use.

Answer (score 0):

A unique index prevents duplicate rows from being added.

Unlike the uniqueness validation built into activerecord, this isn't subject to race conditions - is a cast iron guarantee there will never be duplicate values (other than NULL, if the column allows null values)